# Non bootable iMac what Ubuntu can I use to use as startup DVD

Tags: boot

When I start my iMac I get the apple logo and the swirling gear then it freezes in this position. I have tried

1. Command-R during startup---it can't find recovery partition
2. Press Shift during startup - nothing happens
3. Press D during startup
4. It cannot find a "bootable cache"

I have "heard" that Ubuntu can be used to at least start the Mac and maybe it will load programs from the mac to correct my startup problem

I need to know which version of Ubuntu I should use for a bootable DVD or USB stick and what kind of format does Ubuntu have to be in…. Ie. Iso, or what.

Answer (score 0):

Highly dependent on the version of hardware. Is it 32 or 64 bit hardware? 32-Bit EFI? Many things need to be added to a proper question for a thorough answer.

Long answer cut short: The standard 14.04LTS Ubuntu AMD-64 image should work. If not, try the 14.04LTS Ubuntu AMD-64 **for Mac** if the first doesn't work.

Ideally, burn the .ISO to a DVD or CD. You can put the install bits on a USB device if you have the wherewithall ([www.PenDriveLinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) has good utils and help for doing this via Windows. `dd` is your friend when doing it within Linux.)

For more specific answers, more detailed information is needed.